# local storage get item will gone when i refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html

im new javascript learner,and i have problem to display the local storage.getitem value when i will refresh the page,can any one help me please,and thank you for the help,this is my code;

```
function myFunction() {
  var c = document.getElementById('myinput').value;
  historyarr.push(c);

  localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(historyarr))
  console.log(typeof(historyarr))
  displayonpage(historyarr)
}

function displayonpage(c) {
  return result.innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).join('<br>')
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't happen automatically. Something in your code must be overwriting it.

Comment: How do you set `historyarr`?

Comment: When do you call `myFunction`?